# Cannot drawImage specified by "content" or "background-image" rather than "src"

Tags: javascript, canvas, webkit, drawimage, getimagedata

Since it is impossible to specify an image-set using the `src` DOM attribute, I'm using `-webkit-image-set` to specify the image contents, like this:

```
<img id="imgTest" />
...
#imgTest {
    background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(icon1x.jpg) 1x,url(icon2x.jpg) 2x);
}
```

The image content loads fine, depending on the device pixel ratio. Now, I need to dump the image into a canvas. Here's my code:

```
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 20;
c.height = 20;
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("imgTest"), 0, 0);

// Let's see what we've got in the canvas.
var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 2, 2).data;
```

At this point, `data` is a zero-filled array (and the actual image is clearly not empty). If I set the `src` attribute for `#imgTest` to e.g. `icon2x.png`, the `data` contents reflect the actual image.

Any idea if it is possible to dump contents of an image containing a `-webkit-image-set` into a cavas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with -webkit-image-set, nor your code, and couldn't recreate what you are suggesting. So ultimately, I have no idea.

Hoewever, I am familiar enough with HTML and javascript to guess that the image element either hasn't loaded yet, or has different data spaces for the background, and the actual image, and that drawImage() uses the actual image data. So I would suggest using the src property, and using and onload handler to draw the image when it, or the body has finished loading.

Another option would be to create a hidden image element with the src property set and use that data after it loads.

Comment: __"Since it is impossible to specify an image-set using the src DOM attribute, I'm using -webkit-image-set to specify the image contents..."__

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov Ohhh.. After some research, I now know what you are talking about. The answer is still no. Just like in your code, image-set (with any prefix) is for background-image through css. So the background data has nearly nothing to do with the actual information stored by the element. The drawImage() function puts the content of the image onto the canvas. So, being that there is no image content for the image, there is no data to put. My apologies. I wasn't sure exactly what you were trying to accomplish. Though my original solution still stands if you have access to the url and js.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the hint. Still, would be great to be able to snapshot images with image-sets...